# How to store a dynamic JSON data into a database in PHP?

Tags: php, json

I got a JSON data that returns the last Bitcoin's ticker from URL. The data (ticker) is updated in 60 secs. How can I save all tickers dynamically into a database? I'd like to create a history of Bitcoin's tickers.

Follow the code below.

```
<?php
// init curl object    
    $ch = curl_init();

// define options
$optArray = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/v2/ticker/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60

);

// apply those options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);

// execute request and get response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$phpArray = json_decode ($response);

 ?>
```

Comment: What is it about your code that doesn't do what you want it to do?

Comment: It works for the last ticker.  Actually I'd like to store all tickers into a database

Comment: You can convert your Json data into array and run a loop to save the last updated value in database.

Comment: How can I run this loop to save the last ticker in database?

Comment: So every 60 seconds you want to add new rows with new information about the tickers or just update the current row's information for the tickers?

Comment: I just wanna add new rows of tickers in database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you should never store JSON data in a database (or other serialized data as a column in a database). That is SQL code smell of the highest order. Instead, decode the JSON and store the actual values.

Here's a table for you:

```
CREATE TABLE `so`.`ticker_history` (
  `ticker_history_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ticker_history_high` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL,
  `ticker_history_low` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL,
  `ticker_history_vol` DOUBLE NULL,
  `ticker_history_last` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL,
  `ticker_history_buy` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL,
  `ticker_history_sell` DECIMAL(10,10) NULL,
  `ticker_history_date` DATETIME NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ticker_history_id`));
```

Now, here's some updated (untested) code for you:

```
<?php
// init curl object    
    $ch = curl_init();

// define options
$optArray = array(
    CURLOPT_URL => 'https://www.mercadobitcoin.net/api/v2/ticker/',
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 60

);

// apply those options
curl_setopt_array($ch, $optArray);

// execute request and get response
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$phpArray = json_decode ($response);

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=testdb;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'dbuser';
$password = 'dbpass';

try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}


$sql = "INSERT INTO `so`.`ticker_history`
        ( `ticker_history_high`
        , `ticker_history_low`
        , `ticker_history_vol`
        , `ticker_history_last`
        , `ticker_history_buy`
        , `ticker_history_sell`
        , `ticker_history_date`
        )
        VALUES
        ( :ticker_history_high
        , :ticker_history_low
        , :ticker_history_vol
        , :ticker_history_last
        , :ticker_history_buy
        , :ticker_history_sell
        , :ticker_history_date
        )";


$date = new DateTime(strtotime("@" . $phpArray->date ));

$values = [ 'ticker_history_high' = $phpArray->high
          , 'ticker_history_low'  = $phpArray->low
          , 'ticker_history_vol'  = $phpArray->vol
          , 'ticker_history_last' = $phpArray->last
          , 'ticker_history_buy'  = $phpArray->buy
          , 'ticker_history_sell' = $phpArray->sell
          , 'ticker_history_date' = $date->format("Y-m-d H:i:s")
          ];

$stmt = $dbh->prepare($sql);
$result = $stmt->execute($values);

if($result === false) die($stmt->errorInfo()[2] . " @ " . __FILE__ . ":" . __LINE__);
```

**Note** I have used decimal 10,10 as the data type. You should really look up the maximum number of significant digits and adjust accordingly.

**Continually checking**

PHP is not the best option to do live feeds like this. Its multithreading model is not as good as Python. And, if running in Apache, it starts a thread, does work, and ends the request. However - that's not to say it cannot be done: In order to continually poll, you would need to start it from the command line, and build a loop that polls the URL in question at a given interval. A simple while() loop that executes your curl statement and looks for changes would suffice. When a change is detected (current return json !== last return json) then store the new values in the DB.

You also need to worry about pounding the server and getting yourself banned. Check too frequently, and you're likely to get firewalled off.

Also... usually... if you are dealing with a live feed, you would have the ability to open a socket and receive data being sent from the host. You can do that in PHP, but, it's clunky compared to other languages. This is just an FYI... since your use case above is specific to requesting the JSON values from the URL in your question.

Comment: This will fetch once; the OP is asking for a solution that will check continually, and update the DB with the latest value every 60 secs.

Comment: I answered that above in the comments below the OP. Now, I've moved my comments into the answer.